# GPL-FE (font-exception) on Apple App Store?

Tags: gpl, apple-app-store, gpl-font-exception

It seems that [GPL is not compatible with the Apple App Store](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/2114/are-there-any-gpl-like-licenses-for-apple-app-store) due to the differences regarding Apple's ability to impose further restrictions.

Does this also affect fonts bundled with the app?

In other words - can one use fonts that are licensed under GPL-FE (font exception) with an iOS app? (both from the GPL and Apple's perspective)

Answer (score 1):

This is ultimately an answer for Apple to provide.

The GPL-FE allows it use in documents without much obligation.
If I were you I would create a minimal app with very explicit and clear embedding of the font under GPL + GPL-FE including license and notices and post that to the app store to see if Apple bans it or not.